# How to Validate Forms inside an ngb-accordion

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I have implemented an `ngb-accordion` which contains a form inside it with a couple of input fields. I want to display an icon with a checkmark when the form is valid(in this case when all forms are just filled without empty fields) and in all other cases it displays a 'X' mark icon. These icons appear in the `ngb-panel` heading just before the title.

I assigned required property to all fields and a method in the component file checks if the form is valid or not.

SCSS and HTML files-

```css
input[type="text"],
select.form-control{
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}
input[type="number"],
select.form-control{
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}
input[type="text"]:focus,
select.form-control:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color:rgb(31, 14, 187);
}
input[type="number"]:focus,
select.form-control:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color:darkred;
}
::ng-deep .collapse {
    transition: max-height .55s, opacity .35s ease-in-out;
    max-height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block !important;
  
    &.show {
      max-height: 100rem;
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  
  ::ng-deep .accordion {
    .card {
      margin-bottom: 0 !important;
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .04) !important;
  
      .card-header {
        // padding-top: 0;
        color: #000000;
        padding: 0;
  
        button {
          padding: 1.2rem;
          width: 100%;
  
          span {
            float: left;
            font-size: 1.2rem;
          }
        }
      }
  
      .card-body {
        padding: 1rem;
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
 <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
           <!-- ngb Accordion starts -->
           <ngb-accordion [destroyOnHide]='false' [closeOthers]="true">
            
              <ngb-panel id="panel3">
                 <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
                     <span *ngIf=" !myFormIsInvalid()">   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-x-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
                        <path d="M4.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 7.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708L8.707 8l2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 8.707l-2.646 2.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L7.293 8 4.646 5.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"
                        style="color: red;border-color: red;"/>
                        
                      </svg>&nbsp;</span>
                      <span><svg *ngIf="myFormIsInvalid()" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-check-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
                        <path d="M10.97 4.97a.235.235 0 0 0-.02.022L7.477 9.417 5.384 7.323a.75.75 0 0 0-1.06 1.06L6.97 11.03a.75.75 0 0 0 1.079-.02l3.992-4.99a.75.75 0 0 0-1.071-1.05z" style="color: green;"/>
                      </svg>&nbsp;</span>
                    <span>More Details </span>
                 </ng-template>
                 <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
     
                    <form #form3="ngForm" style="padding-left:20px;">
                
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name" class="control-label">Email<sup style="color: red;font-size:medium;">*</sup></label>
                            <input type="text" required #email ngModel name="Email" class="form-control" id="email">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name" class="control-label">Phone<sup style="color: red;font-size:medium;">*</sup></label>
                            <input type="number" #phone ngModel required name="Phone" class="form-control" id="pone">
                          </div>  
                         
                          </form> 
                 </ng-template>
              </ngb-panel>
              
           </ngb-accordion>
          
        </div>
     </div>
```

Typescript Component file-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core'
import { NgForm }   from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-collapsedemo',
  templateUrl: './collapsedemo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./collapsedemo.component.scss']
})
export class CollapsedemoComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('form3') myForm: NgForm | undefined;
  constructor() { }
  

  myFormIsInvalid(): boolean {
  
     
     if (this.myForm?.valid) {
         return true;
     }
     else
     {
     return false;}

  }


  
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    
  }

}
```

The below image is the result I am getting but i did not enter the Phone field if you observe carefully so it should not yet show the green tick it must be a 'X' mark. For some reason it only checks if the first field is filled or not. If the first field is not filled it shows the 'X' icon as it should but it changes when i fill only the first field.

[image: The result]

Please tell me why is the behavior this way and if there is an alternative way of doing things for my requirement , please mention the best way to do it as well.

Comment: From what I see you missed to add `ngModel` to your phone input

Comment: @lbsn Oh yes, i have missed it here (will edit it  now) but it doesn't change the result in any way .It is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your check function is called `myFormIsInvalid` it's actually returning `true` if the form IS valid. So first of all change your function:

```
myFormIsInvalid(): boolean {
     if (this.myForm?.valid) {
        return false;
     } else {
        return true;
     }
}
```

Then check you're declaring the right conditions in your HTML template: so `*ngIf="myFormIsInvalid()"` then `color:red`, `*ngIf="!myFormIsInvalid()"` then `color:green`,

That being said, you can check your form validity directly in the template, since you have a template variable `#myForm`: `*ngIf="myForm.valid"` or `*ngIf="myForm.invalid"`

Comment: This doesn't change anything because i already gave the correct corresponding check directives to both icons `*ngIf=" !myFormIsInvalid()"` for when form is invalid and `*ngIf=" myFormIsInvalid()"` for green tick icon when form is valid. But I understand what your'e saying as it is not a good practice .Also using `#myForm: *ngIf="myForm.valid"` won't work as it throws an error for undefined object.

Comment: If you meant using `*ngif="form3.valid` , it also doesn't work as it throws error TS2339 "property not present in type"  error hence, the method in TS component file.

Comment: Here's a simplified example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zk8wkr

Comment: I think the example you cited works because form is not nested inside an accordion and you are not trying to access its instance variable outside the accordion , will you try doing it in an accordion and display the icon on accordion panel?

Comment: i appreciate it man.Don't know what was wrong with mine.Definitely somethings were conflicting. i removed it all ,wrote it again ,its working fine now no more errors.here's the link https://angular-nauurt-4re71f.stackblitz.io    editor link  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nauurt-4re71f?file=src/app/accordion-basic.html